# What killed my Arduino nano?

Tags: arduino-nano, bootloader, uploading

Yesterday evening everything worked well. Today morning I am trying to upload sketch to the Arduino (nano china, CH340) and get the following:

```
Writing |

avrdude: stk500_paged_write(): (a) protocol error, expect=0x14, resp=0x00

############avrdude: stk500_cmd(): programmer is out of sync

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
```

Check wiring, settings, cable, another PC. The same result.
Took another Arduino from the same supply. Works.

What could damage my Arduino nano? Static voltage? This is the first time in 3 years of insensitive playing with Arduino. I was told that Arduino nano is quite tolerant to static voltage.

What can I do with this damaged Arduino? Is it possible to restore it?
The boards is still recognizable by PC and blinks with leds when it is connected.

Comment: why are you so certain that it is damaged?

Comment: Since the Arduino is still recognized, try to open a serial monitor and send some data to the Arduino. The RX LED should light up shortly. That would show, that the serial data is still transmitted. Then you can try to burn the bootloader again via an another Arduino

Comment: Could be that the flash in the main chip is dead and the data isn't being written correctly. That's what you get when you buy boards made with chips taken from the factory reject bin.

Comment: i saw that message a few years ago. iirc, rebooting my pc fixed it.